# How find this maxtrix with the determinant contain a Vandermonde maxtrix

Tags: linear-algebra

let the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&\cdots &1&2\\
1&2&\cdots&(n-1)&3\\
1&2^2&\cdots&(n-1)^2&5\\
\vdots&\vdots&\cdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
1&2^{n-2}&\cdots&(n-1)^{n-2}&1+2^{n-2}\\
2&3&\cdots&n&5
\end{bmatrix}$$

Find the $\det{(A)}$

I know this matrix contain a Vandermonde determinant,But I fell  this Bordered determinant
not easy deal it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. What is the sum of the first two columns?

Comment: @Raff I thought a hint would be more useful than a complete solution here. Are you saying you think this answer is inappropriate?

Comment: nice observation.